# A ton of Glass.Mapper INFO messages in logs

Tags: glass-mapper

So, I just upgraded to 8.2 Update 2 along with Glass.Mapper 4.3.4.196.

I now see a ton of Glass.Mapper INFO messages in my logs.   This adds a ton of noise to the logs.  Is there a reason this is happening or is this normal behavior.

```
1920 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {25363DC2-49BC-4FB9-84FF-F9164BE6CC3E}
1920 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {25363DC2-49BC-4FB9-84FF-F9164BE6CC3E}
1920 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {25363DC2-49BC-4FB9-84FF-F9164BE6CC3E}
1920 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {54661361-3C46-4AAA-A82B-6D649F43917F}
1920 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {1B427610-DB06-4F5B-AD35-8F1E8B8FD56B}
6720 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}
6720 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {9DC3117B-367E-4510-AB61-490DDC8359A5}
6720 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {FD8ED973-34E5-4544-9886-9269BA4C1227}
6720 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {729DA297-DB63-4362-B835-E3D4E0CC90E5}
6720 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {AF675ECD-84AC-4110-A334-EB1CA2A34452}
6720 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {25363DC2-49BC-4FB9-84FF-F9164BE6CC3E}
6720 07:45:39 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {5281E350-9958-457F-8D37-FD98134FC9A4}
1920 07:45:40 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {9D5CCD1F-4519-4633-BDFE-72AC41131609}
1920 07:45:41 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {25363DC2-49BC-4FB9-84FF-F9164BE6CC3E}
1920 07:45:41 INFO GetModelFromView 0 {5281E350-9958-457F-8D37-FD98134FC9A4}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess is a mistake in code. From my point of view these lines must be on Debug mode not Info mode.

On line 124 we have

```
 Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("GetModelFromView {0} {1}".Formatted(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, args.Rendering.RenderingItem.ID), this);
```

and  this line runs everytime GetModelFromView processor is running.

Please check glass mapper source code :

https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/5136ac34f2159d57966e6a499b3318ff3020bb55/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc/Pipelines/Response/GetModelFromView.cs

This should be fixed in Release 4.3.4.197.

Comment: I would recommend opening a GitHub issue for this so Mike can track it: https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues

Comment: I totally agree with @Chris Smith

Comment: Issue 281 created.   This seems to be a recurrence of the issue outlined in #219

Comment: Must be the Glass Mapper folks are on vacation -- no response to my issue.

Comment: you can write on slack channel :  https://sitecorechat.slack.com/messages/glass/whats_new/

Comment: Will do.  I also just went ahead and forked it, made the change, and made a pull request #282.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber oh nevermind, looks like I can't login into that slack channel.

Comment: what is your mail address?

Comment: Nevermind.  I just realized I was trying to use the wrong email address.  *rolls eyes*

Comment: This appears to be fixed in the latest GlassMapper beta.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are stuck with this old version, you can protect your logfiles from beeing spamed by adding the following XML to the

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
```

node in your sitecore.config:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
  <stringToMatch value="GetModelFromView "/>
  <acceptOnMatch value="false"/>
</filter>
```